# Angular Component doesn't render

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here's my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../assets/css/app.component.css']
})
export class MainVisualComponent {
  main_visual_img:string = "";
  main_visual_desc:string = "";
  main_visual_title:string = "";
  constructor(main_visual_img:string, main_visual_desc:string, main_visual_title:string){
    this.main_visual_img = main_visual_img;
    this.main_visual_desc = main_visual_desc;
    this.main_visual_title = main_visual_title;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<section style="text-align:center">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <visual-item></visual-item>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../assets/css/app.component.css']` the path for them has to be relative from the index.html folder. Most often it is the app folder if you use quickstart or ng-cli project. So it should be `app/app.component.html` etc.

Answer (score 0):

the selector of the component is `app-root`.

just replace the `<visual-item></visual-item>` with `<app-root></app-root>`.

so your code will be:

```
<section style="text-align:center">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <app-root></app-root>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: <visual-item></visual-item> it other component.

Comment: <app-root></app-root> has index.html

Answer (score 0):

It was just component <-> template binding problem.

Doesn't work:

```
<aria-selected="{{first}}" aria-hidden="{{last}}" aria-controls="SliderItem0{{i+1}}" data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="{{i}}">
```

Works:

```
<[attr.aria-selected]="first" [attr.aria-controls]="'SliderItem0'+(i+1)"  data-target="#carousel-example-generic" [attr.data-slide-to]="i">
```